# Jenkins: How to reset job's Build ID to be the same format as Jenkins Global?

Tags: jenkins

For some reason, the environment variable `BUILD_ID` for all jobs of all projects is set to the same as `BUILD_NUMBER`.

The global environment variables by typing `http://jenkins_server/env-vars.html` show the right format `YYYY-MM-DD_hh-mm-ss`. This is shown on the job number 22:

```
BUILD_DISPLAY_NAME  #22
BUILD_ID    22
BUILD_NUMBER    22
```

How to reset `JOB_ID` back to the same as the global, using the same timestamp?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you use the [Zen Timestamp plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ZenTimestamp+Plugin)? If so, you can edit the "Date pattern for the BUILD_ID" configuration under *Manage Jenkins* -> *Configure System* in the Global Properties section.

Comment: I didn't install ZenTimestamp plugin. Now I'm use it. It is changed to Timestamp now. The problem is solved. But I still don't understand why it was change to Build Number.

Comment: I found the answer why the BUILD_ID change to BUILD_NUMBER. Jenkins 1.587 version make BUILD_ID and BUILD_NUMBER return the same value. See this issue.  https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26520.  I'm using ZenTimeStamp as work-around.